# Not getting the array value in xpath

Tags: php, xml, arrays, xpath

**This is my reg.xml:**

```
<childrens>
<child_4 entity_id="4" value="Activities" parent_id="2">
    <child_10066 entity_id="10066" value="Physical1" parent_id="4">
    <child_10067 entity_id="10067" value="Cricket" parent_id="10066">
        <child_10068 entity_id="10068" value="One Day" parent_id="10067"/>
    </child_10067>
    </child_10066>
</child_4>
<child_4331 entity_id="4331" value="Region" parent_id="2">
    <child_5069 entity_id="5069" value="Irungattukottai" parent_id="4331"/>
</child_4331>
</childrens>
```

**This is my `product.xml` file:**

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1"/>
      <region_timezone value="1"/>
      <registrationstatus value="2"/>
      <eventstatus value="2"/>
      <dist_activity value="5"/>
      <dist_activity value="10068"/>
      <dist_activity value="10070"/>
      <dist_region value="5069"/>
      <dist_region value="5069"/>
      <dist_region value="5069"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
      <tab_name value="test2"/>
      <region_timezone value="1"/>
      <registrationstatus value="2"/>
      <eventstatus value="2"/>
      <dist_activity value="5"/>
      <dist_activity value="10069"/>
      <dist_activity value="10070"/>
      <dist_region value="4457"/>
      <dist_region value="7140"/>
      <dist_region value="5069"/>
   </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

**This is my try:**

```
<?php
 $abc= $_POST['name'];
 list($first,$second) = explode('in',$abc);

 $text1[]=$first;
 $text2[]=$second;
 foreach($text1 as $event)
{
$event;
}
foreach($text2 as $region1)
{
$region1;
}
$r = file_get_contents('reg.xml');
$p = file_get_contents('product.xml');

$region = simplexml_load_string($r);
$product = simplexml_load_string($p);

list($entity) = $region->xpath("//*[@value='$event']/@entity_id");
$entity=(string)$entity;
echo "event:- $event, Region:- $region1, entity:- $entity";
 ?>
```

**This is my HTML file:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
$("#filter").click(function(){
    var name = $('#select').val();
    alert(name);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {"name":name} ,
        url: "array.php",
        async: false,       
        success: function(result) { 
        alert(result);
        $("#result").text(result);
        } 
    });   


    });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="select">
    <input  type="button" id="filter" name="button" value="Search">
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**I input this value in the textbox:**
`One Day in Irungattukottai`
I've tried this code but it's not working and it doesn't give me `$entity`.
If I try manually to set `$event` eg:- `$event` =`"One Day"` value then work
So help me out with this, I think my mistake in my `foreach`.
Thanks.

Comment: the `foreach` code looks really weird -- not sure what you're trying to do there. But I think the actual problem you have is with the `explode()`, because it doesn't look at the space on either side of the word 'in', so your `One Day` will end up with a space on the end and `Irungattukottai` will have a space at the start. You could fix that by including the spaces in the `explode()` or by using `trim()` on the two strings it produces.

Comment: yes problem solve... :)

Comment: great! I've posted it as an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreach code looks really weird -- not sure what you're trying to do there. But I think the actual problem you have is with the explode(), because it doesn't look at the space on either side of the word 'in', so your One Day will end up with a space on the end and Irungattukottai will have a space at the start.

You could fix that by including the spaces in the explode() or by using trim() on the two strings it produces.